# Java - Why JComboBox display a blue box around text?

Tags: java, colors, jcombobox

I use a JComboBox in my program, I've changed the foreground and background colors but there is a blue box that surrounds the text even when it hasn't the focus.
I use NetBeans and I didn't find an option to disable it.

Does anybody know how to do?

Screenshot:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @shekharsuman New users can't do that.

Comment: anyway even if site doesn't allow you, upload it to an external site such as [Photobucket](http://photobucket.com) or another one, post the link, and then we can edit your post so image will be visible. Also be sure to post your code as a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue, so we can be more able to help you

Comment: You don't want to disable the blue box[es].  The blue box[es] shows the user which elements he selected.

Comment: It's not the focus box because I've already disabled it and the box is still present even if the component isn't selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the appearance of it, that border is drawn by the Metal look and feel. I don't know how to disable it, but I think this should change its color to the same gray as what you're using for the rest of the combo box, so it will be invisible:

```
((javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel)UIManager.getLookAndFeel())
        .setCurrentTheme(new javax.swing.plaf.metal.OceanTheme() {
    @Override
    protected javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource getSecondary2() {
        return new javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource(0x8B8B8B);
    }
});
```